# How to map two dataset A & B under the condition that Month of dataset A = previous month of dataset B

Tags: r

There are two dataset-'Open_raw_data' and 'exchangeRate'. In the Open_raw_data i want to get the exchange rate basis on the current date column and the currency column. However under the condition that the mapping has to be done with the previous month of exchangeRate.

**Data**

```
Open_raw_data <- structure(list(Current_date = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("11-May-20", 
"15-Jun-20", "27-Apr-20"), class = "factor"), INV_AMOUNT = c(7269.11, 
2367.51, 12694.02), CURRENCY = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "EUR", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

exchange_rate <- structure(list(Currency = structure(c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 13L, 20L, 
5L, 16L, 3L, 17L, 2L, 15L, 4L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 8L, 7L, 
13L, 20L, 5L, 16L, 3L, 17L, 2L, 15L, 4L, 11L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 20L, 14L, 18L, 10L, 12L, 
21L, 9L, 19L), .Label = c("AUD", "CNY", "CZK", "EUR", "GBP", 
"HKD", "IDR", "INR", "KZT", "MAD", "MXN", "NGN", "PLN", "RON", 
"RUB", "SEK", "SGD", "TRY", "UAH", "USD", "VND"), class = "factor"), 
    Year = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
    2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
    2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
    2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
    2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
    2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
    2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
    2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
    2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
    2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
    2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
    2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
    2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
    2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
    2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
    2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
    2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L), Month = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), Exchnage_Rate = c(0.01266, 
    0.01256, 0.01204, 0.01224, 6.6e-05, 6.4e-05, 5.5e-05, 6.16e-05, 
    0.23288, 0.23283, 0.2197, 0.22014, 0.90671, 0.90721, 0.91044, 
    0.91894, 1.18646, 1.16307, 1.12671, 1.14633, 0.09401, 0.09444, 
    0.09037, 0.09348, 0.0396, 0.0331, 0.0366, 0.03691, 0.66551, 
    0.65106, 0.63837, 0.65294, 0.13068, 0.12975, 0.12894, 0.13019, 
    0.01434, 0.01357, 0.0114, 0.01259, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.01192, 6.1e-05, 
    0.22483, 0.90058, 1.11213, 0.09536, 0.03714, 0.63709, 0.12622, 
    0.01283, 1, 0.04824, 0.04625, 0.03803, 0.03885, 0.04053, 
    0.01192, 6.1e-05, 0.22483, 0.90058, 1.11213, 0.09536, 0.03714, 
    0.63709, 0.12622, 0.01283, 1, 0.03859, 0.20928, 0.20821, 
    0.207, 0.20657, 0.20638, 0.20652, 0.15065, 0.14644, 0.14303, 
    0.13266, 0.13203, 0.1297, 0.09419, 0.09447, 0.09344, 0.09283, 
    0.09197, 0.0919, 0.0025, 0.00253, 0.00233, 0.00237, 0.00232, 
    0.00232, 3.91e-05, 3.97e-05, 3.86e-05, 3.91e-05, 3.86e-05, 
    3.83e-05, 0.0024, 0.00237, 0.00204, 0.00214, 0.00221, 0.00222, 
    0.03693, 0.03708, 0.03263, 0.03406, 0.03341, 0.03325, 0.61695, 
    0.59838, 0.55659, 0.60261, 0.60036, 0.6116, 0.1168, 0.11828, 
    0.11845, 0.11863, 0.11616, 0.11474, 0.6114, 0.12609, 0.03737, 
    1, 1.09587, 0.11484, 6.3e-05, 0.0118, 0.03859, 0.22492, 0.01251, 
    0.0954, 0.63841, 0.89127, 0.20652, 0.1297, 0.0919, 0.00232, 
    3.83e-05, 0.00222, 0.03325)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-147L))
```

Code I tried:

```
i1 <- as.numeric(format(open_data$Current_date, '%Y'))
i2 <- as.numeric(format(open_data$Current_date, '%m'))

exchangeRate <- exchangeRate %>% 
  filter(Month == i2 - 1 & Year == i1)

Open_raw_data_f1 <- sqldf("select Open_raw_data.*,exchangeRate.Exchnage_Rate as Exchnage_Rate from Open_raw_data  join
                        exchangeRate on Open_raw_data.Currency =exchangeRate.Currency")
```

Comment: you have 86  months in the second `df` and only 50 entries in the `Current_date` column from the first list. how do you even know which data belongs to which month?

Comment: it will be difficult to share you the complete dataset as it is huge. If its possible can you construct a logical code so that it will be easy for me to implement

Comment: For instance if the current data is 30-Aug-2020 and currency is Euro, then i will need to get the exchange rate  of the previous month i.e Jul 2020 of currency Euro. This is the logic

Comment: i have edited the data, i hope this will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

exchange_rate %>%
  mutate(Date = make_date(Year, Month), .keep = "unused") %>% 
  right_join(Open_raw_data %>% mutate(
               Current_date = dmy(Current_date),
               Prev_date = rollback(Current_date, roll_to_first = T) - months(1)),
             by = c("Date" = "Prev_date", "Currency" = "CURRENCY")) %>%
  select(-Date)

#   Currency Exchnage_Rate Current_date INV_AMOUNT
# 1      EUR             1   2020-04-27    7269.11
# 2      EUR             1   2020-05-11    2367.51
# 3      EUR             1   2020-06-15   12694.02
```

Comment: Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found. -- getting this warning and all NA generated

Comment: it is done, actually there is a problem with the date format. it should be in as.Date(Open_raw_data$Current_date,format = "%d-%b-%y"). which is now working fine in my system. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
merge(transform(exchange_rate, mon = as.Date(paste(Year, Month+1, "01", sep = "-"))),
      transform(Open_raw_data, mon = as.Date(gsub("^\\d+", "01", Current_date), "%d-%b-%y")), 
                by.x = c("mon", "Currency"), by.y = c("mon", "CURRENCY"), all.y = TRUE)
```